# orchard cms removing/deleting content items

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

Just curious as to the thinking behind why when a content item is deleted from orchard all associated database records remain? This goes for any content type and associated parts. Seems a little wasteful to me? I understand I can use the ContentHandler class to tap into OnRemoved and remove ContentPartRecords myself. I just can't see how it makes sense say if I delete a content item that it leaves the RoutePartRecord in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic behind such behavior is that keeping the removed records and flagging them as removed is better than removing them completely. Why?

1. They can be undeleted
2. Keeping the whole history is useful for tracking changes and is also a must-have in many scenarios (for legal reasons).

And also - storage space is extremely cheap these days.

You can also check the [discussion](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/259018) about exactly the same problem on Codeplex.

Comment: Thanks @pszmyd. I just feel like I should avoid duplicate records in my RoutePartRecord table but maybe I should just trust the framework.

Comment: Duplicates can be an issue sometimes - I agree. I've ran into one when, unaware of Orchard removal behavior, declared a table column as unique. Was wondering why it shouted with errors when I tried to re-add a previously removed item? Of course until I found out how it really works.